# what is the frequency response?

Tags: frequency-response, z-transform

I try to work out the simplest system, whose response is $H(z) = 1 + cz + c^2z^2 + c^3z^3 + \cdots = 1 / (1-cz)$

Now, [Z-transform done quick (Fourier connection)](http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2012/08/26/z-transform-done-quick/) and [4.5 Transfer Function, Poles and Zeros](http://dea.brunel.ac.uk/cmsp/Home_Saeed_Vaseghi/Chapter04-Z-Transform.pdf) say that we just need to plug $z => e^{iw}$ to get the frequency response. I am getting single pole at $w = i \ln c$. It is complex. What is the frequency response? The second link says that real coefficients must generate complex poles in pairs. Where is the second pair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frequency response is $1/(1−ce^{iw})$, if you want to get amplitude information you just need to get the magnitude of this complex function and its phase will be the inverse of the phase of $1/(1−ce^{iw})$ or

$$-\arctan (-c\sin w/(1-c\cos w))$$

You can compute the magnitude of the transfer function by:

$$ 1 / sqrt( (-c\sin w)^2 + (1-c\cos w)^2 )$$

Comment: +1 for deleting your comment on the poles and correcting your formula for the phase. Just one more advice/hint: you could write you formulas using Latex commands. This makes them looks much nicer. I'll edit it for you and you can see how it works.

Comment: How do you compute the magnitude of $1/(1-e^{iw})$?

Comment: How did you get the magnitude formula?

Comment: just taking the magnitude of a complex number: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number

Comment: Thanks, I have completely forgot that $e^{iw} = cos + isin$. I have got the same magnitude. It looks like there is a pole every $2 \pi$

Comment: @MattL, thanks. Saying that, I assumed c=1. I plotted the amplitude and got http://goo.gl/gnIY6 I see a pole at every 2Pi.

Comment: OK, for $c=1$ you have a pole at $z=1$, i.e. on the unit circle at frequency $w=0$. What you see is a consequence of the frequency response being periodic with period $2\pi$. What is important is the value at $w=0$ because frequencies higher than $w=\pi$ (i.e. half the sampling frequency) cannot be achieved due to aliasing. For $c=1$ your system is an ideal accumulator: $y(n)=y(n-1)+x(n)$. Its output is unbounded, i.e. the system is unstable. This is the consequence of a pole on the unit circle.

Comment: @Val: in your plot of the magnitude you got a sign wrong. This is why you get real and imaginary parts (which shouldn't be the case for the magnitude of a complex function). See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fsqrt%28sin%28x%29^2%2B%281-cos%28x%29%29^2+%29) for how the magnitude of your filter looks like (with $c=1$).

Answer (score 2):

You need to evaluate $H(z)$ on the unit circle $z=e^{iw}$ in order to get the frequency response (assuming that the system is stable, i.e. the region of convergence contains the unit circle). But your $\mathcal{Z}$-transform looks a bit unusual because for causal signals (or filter impulse responses) you should get negative powers of $z$:

$$H(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x(n)z^{-n}$$

In your case $x(n)=c^n$, $n\ge 0$, so you get

$$H(z)=\frac{1}{1-cz^{-1}}=\frac{z}{z-c}\tag{1}$$

From (1) you see that the pole is at $z_{\infty}=c$. Note that you need to determine the poles of $H(z)$ for general $z$, not on the unit circle $z=e^{iw}$ because stable systems cannot have poles on the unit circle (this is also why you got a complex frequency, which does not make sense). The frequency response is

$$H(e^{iw})=\frac{1}{1-ce^{-iw}}$$

It is true that for real filter coefficients you get complex conjugate pairs of poles and zeros. But this is not the whole truth. You can also get real-valued poles and zeros, and for a first-order system like yours, this must be the case. You need at least a second-order system to get a complex pole pair. In your case you simply got one real pole (assuming that $c$ is a real-valued constant).

Comment: Wait, how is pole $ce{-iw}$ real? I see that it contains complex i in it? It is a line of poles actually because you will have a new pole for every new value of w.

Comment: Have you read my answer? You need to determine the poles in the z-plane, so the pole is at z=c which is real as long as c is real.

Comment: But you say that I must avoid $e^{iw}$ and prompt me to evaluate H(z) at that "point". Actually, I think that it is a line, since it is w-dependent. We have "a" pole at $w = -i \ln c$

Comment: No, you must compute the points in the z-plane for which the denominator of $H(z)$ becomes zero. If you try to compute the zeros of the denominator for $z=e^{iw}$ then you implicitly assume that there must be poles on the unit circle and you're trying to compute the pole frequencies. This would be OK if there were poles on the unit circle, but since there aren't any (unless $|c|=1$), you get a nonsensical (i.e. complex-valued) result for $w$. Why don't you see that the pole $z_{\infty}=c$ is real if $c$ is real?

Comment: Actually, I compute the poles from the $1/(1-e^{iw})$ equation. Resolving $1/(1-e^{iw}) = \infty$ gitves me the poles rather than the unit circle. I do not know how to assume the poles on the unit circle. Resolving equation gives me the whole line of poles, $-i \ln c$, but, they all seem imaginary. No matter which $c$ I choose.

Comment: I'm sorry but you still got it wrong. What is the magnitude of the complex number $e^{iw}$? It is 1, so you're looking at complex numbers with magnitude one. This is, by definition, the unit circle in the complex plane. Please make some effort and try to understand what I've written in my answer. There is no "line of poles". What you're doing only works for $|c|=1$, not otherwise. Solving for $1-e^{iw}=0$ gives you $w=0$, i.e. a pole at frequency 0, just as I've stated in another comment. Again, note that this only works for $|c|=1$.

Comment: There is a cycle of poles!

Comment: You mean that when looking at the magnitude response you see poles at multiples of $2\pi$? There is actually only one pole, you just keep going round the unit circle in the complex plane, and every $2\pi$ you're coming back to where you've already been.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9100/discussion-between-val-and-matt-l)